# Symfony creating choice from entity in form type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a lot of Categories in database.

Here is Category Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     */
    protected $rootCategory;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set rootCategory
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $rootCategory
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setRootCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $rootCategory = null)
    {
        $this->rootCategory = $rootCategory;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rootCategory
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getRootCategory()
    {
        return $this->rootCategory;
    }
}
```

I want to get all categories in my edit form

**EditFormType:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use AppBundle\Controller\CategoryController;

class EditPhotoFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $categoryController = new CategoryController();

        $builder->add('title', 'text');
    $builder->add('description', 'textarea');
        $builder->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Category',
            'choices' => $categoryController->getCategories(),
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_photo_edit';
    }
}

getCategories() 

public function getCategories() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    return $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAll();
    }
```

I am getting next error:

> Error: Call to a member function has() on null

Thats because there is not Doctrine in controller object. Where should i get Doctrine and Repository in this case?
How should i do it correct way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you should **NEVER** instantiate any Controller class yourself. Controller classes are used by Symfony's Kernel to handle a request, and they are loaded automatically with dependencies to do so.

Right here, you don't even need to require the EntityManager in your FormType, because `EntityType` has a built-in option `query_builder` to do what you need:

```
$builder->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Category',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
         return $er->createQueryBuilder('c');
    },
);
```

This should do the trick. (check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) for more details)

However, if one day you really need to import a dependancy inside your Form (whether it is EntityManager or another service), here's how you should do:

A. import the given dependency in your constructor:

```
private $dependency;

public function __construct(Dependency $dependency)
{
     $this->$dependency = $dependency;
}
```

B. Declare your Form as a Service, with your dependency's id as argument:

```
<service id="app.form.type.edit_photo"
         class="AppBundle\Form\Type\EditPhotoFormType">
    <tag name="form.type" />
    <argument type="service" id="app.dependencies.your_dependency" />
</service>
```

Then use `$this->dependency` in your Form wherever you need.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Tried with query_builder, getting error Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given.

Comment: I edited my answer, you have to return a QueryBuilder inside `query_builder`

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Category could not be converted to string. I still dont get how to get this working....

Comment: Now the problem is that Symfony does not know how to display your categories in the `select`. Either define a `__toString` method in Category or use option `choice_label` in EntityType (cf http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label). Anyway, you seem to struggle a lot with Forms, so I advise you to read the full documentation of Forms and EntityType, you can only get better doing this.